# php detect browser width

Tags: php, html, css, screen-size

I have a css media query that resizes and repositions a div. In my html that div has 2 lines but on the smaller screen I would like it displayed as 1 line.

Is there a way to ensure I have:

```
Website Visitors: <?php echo $data; ?>
<div class="fb-like"></div>
```

Instead of:

```
Website Visitors: <?php echo $data; ?>
<br/>
<div class="fb-like"></div>
```

When a screen is less than a fixed amount (in this case 460px)?

I would like to use php or css as they're what I'm using for styling in my css.php file.

Comment: You answered already your question, use media queries. Remove `br` and use margin.

Comment: And please don't use php for styling elements.

Comment: I want to use something (i never said it has to be php) in conjunction with the css. the css margins sound good in theory BUT they won't work quite right for the site i'm putting together. (Mainly because i'm using the same css file for 4 websites)

Comment: I use php to style elements the same way i use php to automate parts of my html. i use a lot of foreach statements based on variables i already have. plus by setting colours as variables once at the start of my css i am able to change the colours of ten elements by changing one line of php. i don't see why i shouldn't use php to style.

Comment: For variables in css it is not necessary to use php. Have a look at SASS/SCSS or LESS. You can save unnecessary traffic.

Comment: the variables are used elsewhere too. not just in the css. plus what's the point in learning yet another language when the ones i know cover everything i need them to.

Comment: Give me an example. Where do you need these variables except css?

Comment: to make the nav menu in a html list

Comment: to make the nav menu in a html list and use the variables to change the styling for each ID, the  `$_GET['page']`, variable which is used on every page,  the  `$_GET['section']`, variable which is used on every page,  to check if the site is undergoing maintenance and change the padding to accommodate the notification as well as display the notification in html.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<br/>` add this in your css (values can be anything you want):

```
.fb-like {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and in your media query:

```
.fb-like {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Not possible with complete PHP you might need to use Javascript too !!
You can try following code to fetch screen width and height!!!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height'])){
    echo 'Screen resolution: ' . $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];
} else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
    $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
}
?>
```